# Jquery submenu script on subdoimains of wordpress doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, submenu

i don't understand why if i try to apply a jquery submenu script on subdomains of wordpress doesn't work properly. I think i have done all right.

I have try to use different jquery lib and i have try to modify the directories of the files, but nothing.

The very strange thing is that this script works perfectly in the main index of the site.
But if i go here for example politica.studionews24.com it doesn't work.

But as you can see from the source i have done like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.studionews24.com/wp-content/themes/network/js/menu.js"></script>
```

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `menu-2` element is missing in the sudomain page.

*Note: Also there is two different versions of jQuery included in the page jQuery 1.6.4 and jQuery 1.10.2 see why is it and remove the old version if it is not really needed*

Comment: But i have included #menu-2 in the style.css for subdomains. Really is missing? For the jquery lib is true, but it could still works also because in the main index i have more than one jquery lib but it works.

Comment: @GiulioBambini the html element is missing

Comment: I have fix the problem. I had actually forgotten the #menu-2 in html.

Comment: @GiulioBambini that was what I was trying to say